# PHP form only pushes one object to array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Whenever a new object of class productEntry is pushed to the array $products, the newest entry is overwriting the last one.

```
    if (isset($_POST['formedit'])){
        $newproduct = new productEntry;
        $newproduct->productid = count($products);
        $newproduct->name = $_POST['productnamefield'];
        $newproduct->weight = $_POST['productweightfield'];
        $newproduct->length = $_POST['productlengthfield'];
        $newproduct->width = $_POST['productwidthfield'];
        $newproduct->height = $_POST['productheightfield'];
        $products[] = $newproduct;
    }
```

This is the output after submitting form once:

`productEntry Object ( [productid] => 0 [name] => 1 [weight] => 1 [length] => 1 [width] => 1 [height] => 1 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 1 [name] => 2 [weight] => 2 [length] => 2 [width] => 2 [height] => 2 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 2 [name] => 3 [weight] => 3 [length] => 3 [width] => 3 [height] => 3 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 3 [name] => 4 [weight] => 4 [length] => 4 [width] => 4 [height] => 4 )`

and then if I submit the form once more with different values

`productEntry Object ( [productid] => 0 [name] => 1 [weight] => 1 [length] => 1 [width] => 1 [height] => 1 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 1 [name] => 2 [weight] => 2 [length] => 2 [width] => 2 [height] => 2 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 2 [name] => 3 [weight] => 3 [length] => 3 [width] => 3 [height] => 3 ) productEntry Object ( [productid] => 3 [name] => 5 [weight] => 5 [length] => 5 [width] => 5 [height] => 5 )`

Comment: I think it could be the last line reassigning the products array. Try changing the last line to `$products[] += $newproduct;`

Comment: sounds like there is a loop involved? It's not clear what the problem is... what's the current output? what's the desired output? what is the input like?

Comment: or is there a database involved afterwards?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. There is a dropdown select which shows the products.

function getOptions($products) {
    $options = '';
    $num = count($products);
    for ($i=0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) {
        $options .= '<option value = "' . $i . '">' . $products[$i]->name . '</option>';
    }
    return $options;
}

Comment: Original question updated for more context.

Comment: unless you safe your data to a database (or a `$_SESSION` var) it _will be lost_ after the script was executed.

Comment: Would adding `session_start(); $_SESSION['products'] = $products;` do it?

Comment: yes, to start with. Then you have to get back this data with something like `if(isset($_SESSION['products']) { $products = $_SESSION['products']; } else { $products = []; }` (before you add the new items)

Comment: This data then only persists for _one_ user and only for the time of his session.

Comment: This is what i have at the top: `session_start();

// create array for products
$products = array();
$_SESSION['products'] = $products;
if(isset($_SESSION['products'])) { 
    $products = $_SESSION['products']; 
} 
else { 
    $products = [];
}
$product1 = new productEntry;
$product1->productid = 0;
$product1->name = '1';
$product1->weight = 1;
$product1->length = 1;
$product1->width = 1;
$product1->height = 1;
' and so forth for $product 2 and 3

'$products[] = $product1;
$products[] = $product2;
$products[] = $product3;` It is still giving the same result.